# What does 私様 means?

Tags: expressions

I see that apparently this word is used by a character in a videogame called danganropa. It's a word like boku, atashi or something like that? Or it's something different? It's used to call yourself superior or something like that maybe? Maybe it's her nickname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a sort of 役割語{やくわりご}, though I don't any other character in fiction that uses it. 私様{わたくしさま} makes her 'regal' personality sound both queenly and extremely arrogant, which is the exact vibe she is going for. Interestingly, in the first game she pairs it with more modern 'regal, haughty woman' speech, but in the second it's an older style. For example, in the first she would probably phrase 'I have been waiting for you!' as 私様は待っていたわよ while using that personality, but in the second she'd phrase it as 私様は待っておったぞ.

Comment: Also worth mentioning fictional characters referring to themselves as 俺様 being a fairly common trope, with 私様 being a novelty gender-swapped derivative of such, I would guess.

Answer (score 3):

It means “I/me/myself” but it is unusual to use this form rather than わたし or わたくし. Referring to yourself (or your inner circle) with an honorific is very impolite. These titles (such as さん, 氏, or 様) are typically used to refer to others, just like you don't call yourself "Mr/Ms", "Sir/Madam", "the Right Honorable", or "Majesty". It comes across as over-confident and arrogant, belittling those you are speaking to.

You may encounter this in fiction as part of characterization. These are not situations that would occur in daily life. It would be rare to hear this in conversational Japanese and should not be used out of context, especially with people you don't know, are older than you, or are more senior.